# One to many relationships with Eloquent

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a **bulletins** table, and also a **comments** table. When I create a new bulletin post, how do I create a new row in **comments** by default, and have `bulletins->comments_id` correspond with the ID of the row in **comments** that I just created ?

This is how I have it creating rows in **bulletins** currently :

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->bulletin = new Bulletin;
$user->bulletin->creator_id = $id;
$user->bulletin->type = Input::get('type');
$user->bulletin->title = Input::get('title');
$user->bulletin->content = Input::get('bulletinEdit');
$user->bulletin->touch();
$user->bulletin->save();
```

Also, is there a way I can fill `$user->bulletin->creator_id` automatically ? It's a foreign key that relates back to the user, so I was hoping that it would know to fill it with the `$user->id`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it:

```
$bulletin = new Bulletin;
$bulletin->type = Input::get('type');
$bulletin->title = Input::get('title');
$bulletin->content = Input::get('bulletinEdit');

$user = User::find($id);
$user->bulletin()->save($bulletin);
```

And what is that?

```
$user->bulletin->touch();
```

Don't do it, it's wrong, you don't want to `update` anything that wasn't even created.

Comment: Eloquent updates timestamps for you, no need to do that manually. `touch` is used whenever you want to update timestamp but nothing else - using `save` won't update it unless there is anything 'dirty', meaning anything changed since data retrieval.